# How to properly iterate over each row for a set of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply `strip()` function to all rows for a set of `pandas` dataframes,
I am trying to figure out how to convert this set of dataframes into a class and then apply a `strip()` function, as the error is the next one:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Here's my attempt to iterate over each row:

```
for df in (df1, df2):
    df1 = df1.strip()
    df2 = df2.strip()
```

### data

```
import pandas as pd

df1= pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [' hey ' , ' world ', "-"], 'col2': [' hello ' , "-", ' world ']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col3': [' brazil ' , ' china ', "-"], 'col4': [' russia ' , "-", ' india ']})
```

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (without the for loop):

```
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

Or a bit less verbose:

```
strip = lambda s: s.str.strip()

df1.apply(strip)
df2.apply(strip)
```

Or with `replace`:

```
trailings = ['^\s+', '\s+$']
df1.replace(trailings, '', regex=True)
df2.replace(trailings, '', regex=True)
```

If you want to use loop, then update the **data** of the dataframe, instead of reassigning them:

```
list_df = [df1, df2]
for df in [df1,df2]:
    # df = df.apply(strip) wouldn't work
    df[:] = df.apply(strip)
```